# AWS Boto3 authentication before loading resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, boto3, botocore

I want to authenticate after initializing a session, without calling any resource method.
I'm doing something like this.

```
session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='profile')
s3 = session.resource('s3')
object = s3.Object('bucket', 'key')
```

I want to authenticate after session and before s3 so that this session initialized and authenticated. So that I can use it in my code

Comment: I think you'll find `session` to be a somewhat inaccurate name for what this object really is/does.  Each request is authenticated independently, by the service, as it is sent.  Everything is stateless, and there are not really any "sessions." ...but it's not clear what you are implying with "so that I can use it in my code."  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am writing a script that will list all keys withing on bucket and do some stuff e.g. copy it to another bucket. Therefore I need to enter my MFA token. I just want to get asked by the session that I have to enter my MFA token so that the exception handling will be at point of session and not at resource base.

Comment: MFA requires that you use your credentials to call [`GetSessionToken`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetSessionToken.html) in STS, which returns new, temporary credentials that you'll use (instead of your own) to make requests. Using these credentials will cause  policy `"Condition": {"Bool": {"aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"}}` to match. Unless boto3 provides some magic wrapping here, the MFA validation would always be a separate/earlier step -- you wouldn't get the temporary credentials without a valid MFA value in the request.